# Either application or integration test Spring context creation fails due to properties file location type

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, properties

Our application should use a `.properties` file which is created in deploy time on the host filesystem, thus it is not being bundled with the application `.war` in build time. It is opened and read by a loader class during the Spring application context creation

```
<bean id="propertiesLoader" class="com....PropertiesLoader">
  <property name="propertiesFileLocation" value="${PROPERTIES_FILE_LOCATION}"/>
  ...
```

where the file path value of `PROPERTIES_FILE_LOCATION` is defined in the`application.properties` file in `src\main\resources` of the application's `-web` maven module

```
PROPERTIES_FILE_LOCATION=/home/.../propertyfilename.properties
```

and the type of the `propertiesFileLocation` field is `String` and it is being accessed via `new FileInputStream(propertiesFileLocation)` in `PropertiesLoader.java` class

With this setup the application context creation is successful. However, we also have some integration tests in our project which also setup a Spring context for their execution. We though to store a copy of `propertyfilename.properties` file into `src\test\resources` of the `-it` maven module and refer it from its `it.properties` like

```
PROPERTIES_FILE_LOCATION=classpath:somedirectory/propertyfilename.properties
```

however during the creation of the integration test context we receive the following exception

```
[ERROR] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
with name 'propertiesLoader' defined in URL 
[ERROR] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:somedirectory\propertyfilename.properties  
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Now if we modify the type of the `propertiesFileLocation` field to `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` and we access it via `propertiesFileLocation.getInputStream()` in `PropertiesLoader.java`, that makes the integration tests context creation succesful, but at the same the real application context creation fails with

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertiesLoader' defined in URL 
[file:/.../tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/_/loader/conf/spring/springmvc/springmvc-util.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/home/.../propertyfilename.properties]
```

This seems to be a "deadlock" situation, as either the application or the integration test context creation fails. Is there a way with which both context can be succesfully created?

Comment: Prefix in `application.properties` with `file:` instead of no prefix.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thank you, that seems to solve it. Do you care to elaborate it to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource loading is quite well documenten in the [Spring References Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-implementations). When you don’t prefix the resources with the location to load it from it will default to the default location of the `ApplicationContext`. For the web application that will be the root of the archive, basically what is in the `WEB-INF` directory. \

You want to load a file resource for this prefix the resource with `file:` and in your test use `classpath:` to have it loaded from the `classpath. This way it will work regardless of which default location the application context uses.